# Vuex Module Decorators: Access vuex module from this.$store does not register the module

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, store, vuex-modules

In my project, I created a small vuex module using `vuex-module-decorators`. But when trying to access it directly from `this.$store` or `$store` in the template part, it does not trigger the registration.

Here is an example:

```
// exampleModule.ts
import { Module, getModule, Mutation, VuexModule } from 'vuex-module-decorators';
import store from '@/store';

@Module({
  dynamic: true,
  namespaced: true,
  name: 'example',
  stateFactory: true,
  store,
})
class Example extends VuexModule {
  private work: boolean = false;

  get isWorking() {
    return this.work;
  }

  @Mutation
  setWorking(status: boolean) {
    this.work = status;
  }
}

export default getModule(Example);

// App.vue
<template>

  <div> 
    first attempt: {{ $store.getters['example/isWorking'] }} // this is not working
    second attempt: {{ isWorking }} // this is not working too
  </div> 
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import Vue from 'vue';

  export default Vue.extend({
    computed: {
      isWorking() {
        return this.$store.getters['example/isWorking'];
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

The only way I get to to actually register the module and to make it work, is to import it directly in the component, like this:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import Vue from 'vue';
  import exampleModule from '@/store/modules/example/exampleModule';

  export default Vue.extend({
    computed: {
      isWorking() {
        return exampleModule.isWorking;
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Am I missing something here ? Is this the wanted behavior ? Thanks.

Btw, i opened an issue on their github repository, but i still don't have any answers, so here i am

https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-module-decorators/issues/190

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, so I will answer here.
Did you import your store in the main.js file?
Maybe that's the problem.
Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Since the module you are using is dynamic, you have to register it before using it.

```
this.$store.registerModule('example', Example) // Don't forget to import your module
```

Note that it is important to register before using, so I would like to suggest to register it in `created()`. You might consider adding a condition to check whether the module is already added or not. Check this out https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/833

Hope this help (:

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that you imported the module in the index.ts file of your store and `({ namespaced })` is set to true in your module. (something you already did)

Example folder structure:

```
/store
└── /modules
    └── Example.ts
    └── Other.ts
    └── Products.ts
    └── ...
└── index.ts
```

index.ts

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

import { Example } from './modules/Example'
import { Other } from './modules/Other'
import { Products } from './modules/Products'

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    Example,
    Other, // Another module.
    Products // Another module.
  }
})
```

Example.ts

```js
import { Module, VuexModule, Mutation } from 'vuex-module-decorators'

@Module({ namespaced: true })
export class Example extends VuexModule {
  work = false // You don't need to specify with work: boolean as TS will know the type by itself.

  @Mutation
  setWorking(status: boolean) {
    this.work = status
  }

  get isWorking() {
    return this.work
  }
}
```

App.vue

```js
<template>
  <div> 
    first attempt: {{ $store.getters['Example/isWorking'] }}
  </div> 
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

First import getModule and your created vuex module

```
import { getModule } from 'vuex-module-decorators'
import MyModule from '@/store/modules/MyModule'
```

Then you basically you want to initialize a data property having the result of getModule, passing your module and this.$store

```
// .js
myModule: getModule(MyModule, this.$store)

// .ts
myModule: MyModule = getModule(MyModule, this.$store)
```

Finally, you're able to access any state, getters, actions etc using your module directly inside your component.

```
this.myModule.myData

this.myModule.myAction()

// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issue. i solved it like this.

store/index.ts

```
import { Store } from 'vuex';
export const store = new Store({});
```

store/example.ts

```
import { Action, Module, Mutation, VuexModule } from 'vuex-module-decorators';
import { store } from '@/store';

@Module({
    name: 'example',
    namespaced: true,
    stateFactory: true,
    dynamic: true, // <--- important part
    store
})
export default class Example extends VuexModule {
  work = false 

  @Mutation
  setWorking(status: boolean) {
    this.work = status
  }

  get isWorking() {
    return this.work
  }
}
```

app.vue

```html
<template>
  <div> 
    first attempt: {{ $store.getters['example/isWorking'] }}
  </div> 
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

In dynamic vuex modules the first line in `.ts` must be the store import:

```
import { store } from '@/store';
// rest of the module...
```